# jquery checkbox auto-select other from same table by class

Tags: jquery

I want to auto-select checkboxes when I check other checkboxes.

Here is the code I am using and is not working:

```
<table class='block'>
<tr>
<td>
<input class='cb1' type='checkbox'><label>Checkbox 1</label>
</td>
<td>
<input class='cb2' type='checkbox'><label>Checkbox 2</label>
</td>
<td>
<input class='cb2' type='checkbox'><label>Checkbox 2</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class='block'>
<tr>
<td>
<input class='cb1' type='checkbox'><label>Checkbox 1</label>
</td>
<td>
<input class='cb2' type='checkbox'><label>Checkbox 2</label>
</td>
<td>
<input class='cb2' type='checkbox'><label>Checkbox 2</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block .cb1').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {

                $(this).parent().find('.cb2').attr('checked','checked');
            }
        else
            {
                $(this).parent().find('.cb2').removeAttr('checked');
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am trying to make it to only check 'cb2' from the same table where 'cb1' was checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `parent()` with `closest('table')` (or `closest('tr')`, for the HTML shown) call. See, the immediate parents of checkbox elements are `<td>` elements - which obviously do not contain any other checkboxes. You need to go further up the DOM to find the element which has all the other checkboxes as descendants.

Answer (score 0):

your code is searchin for a element with class `cb2` inside `<td>` sine your selector is `.parent()` .. it has to go through 3rd parent level to reach the `<table>` element..

so use `parents()` and `eq()`

```
$(this).parents().eq(3).find('.cb2').attr('checked','checked');

*OR*

$(this).parents().eq(2).find('.cb2').attr('checked','checked'); // since all your checkbox is under <tr>
```

here is the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/MKSgf/

Answer (score -1):

Try this code because you eith parent() select the td not the tr

```
(this).parent().parent().find('.cb2').attr('checked','checked');
```

If you want to select the first cb2 checkbox try this

```
 $(this).parent().parent().find('.cb2').first().attr('checked','checked');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LFWyV/1/)

Comment: In the shown structure all checkboxes are the first (element) children nodes; `first-child` expression is meaningless.